# Using formtastic with blueprint.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, blueprint-css

I'm using Blueprint for css for laying out my side.  I have also started using Formtastic but I have problems laying it out with the grid system.  Does anybody have any guidelines or pointers on how to make these two work together?

Regards,
Johann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've stopped using Formtastic and instead use https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form and have have no problems whatsoever making it play well with blueprint.

Although I should say, that my reason for switching to simple_form had nothing to do with blueprint, I just prefer its api and features to formtastic's.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I will try simple_forms.